# How to use DynamoDBMapper to batchSave entity skip null attributes

Tags: java, amazon-dynamodb

I use the `UPDATE_SKIP_NULL_ATTRIBUTES` as config the create a mapper, so that I could save entity and skip null attributes. It did work. But, when I invoke batchSave, it not works.

Anyone who know the problem?

````
```
DynamoDBMapperConfig update_config = DynamoDBMapperConfig.builder()
        .withSaveBehavior(DynamoDBMapperConfig.SaveBehavior.UPDATE_SKIP_NULL_ATTRIBUTES)
            .build();
mapper = new DynamoDBMapper(client, update_config);

List<DynamoDBMapper.FailedBatch> failedBatches = mapper.batchSave(one, two);
```
````

Finally, I found the null attributes had been updated to DB which I don't want to. I just want to save the attrs with not null value.

Answer (score 5):

Well, I read the doc of DynamoDBMapper, found that it really not support the feature of  `batch-save-skip-null-attributes` .

Here is the Link:
[batchSave](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/dynamodbv2/datamodeling/DynamoDBMapper.html#batchWrite-java.lang.Iterable-java.lang.Iterable-com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.datamodeling.DynamoDBMapperConfig-)

The reason is:

`config - Only DynamoDBMapperConfig.getTableNameOverride() and DynamoDBMapperConfig.getBatchWriteRetryStrategy() are considered. If TableNameOverride is specified, all objects in the two parameter lists will be considered to belong to the given table override. In particular, this method always acts as if **SaveBehavior.CLOBBER** was specified *regardless* of the value of the config parameter.`

So, I have no idea how to just update one field of many entities. I have to get all by PK, then save them.